# Solving linear equations over $\mathbb{Z}$ using Smith normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-diophantine-equations, smith-normal-form

To solve linear equations over $\mathbb{Z}$ we have a system of linear equations represented by some integer matrix $A$ of $n \times m$ dimension and $b \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. Such that solving $Ax = b$ gives our solutions.

We can solve $Ax = b$ by using the smith normal form of $A$ given by $A = UDV$ with $U \in GL(m, \mathbb{Z})$, $V \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ and $D$ is some integer diagonal matrix following the properties of Smith normal form (the diagonals $d_i | d_{i+1}$).

Then we can solve $Ax = b$ in the following way, let $y = Vx$ and $c = U^{-1}b$, so we have $Dy = c$, solving $Dy = c$ is simple as $D$ is diagonal, then for the elements of $y$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_l \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} = 
    \begin{pmatrix} c_1/d_1 \\ c_2/d_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_l / d_l \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where rank$(D) = l$, we then have $x = V^{-1}y$ to acquire our solutions.

My question is as we are looking for integer solutions, what if $c_i/d_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ is not an integer? Certainly just because $c_i/d_i$ is not an integer it doesn't meant for $x = V^{-1}y$, $x_i$ is not an integer, but if $x$ attained through this method also does not have all integer solutions does that mean no integer solutions exist - afterall SNF is unique for some integer matrix $A$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, a vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ with integer entries is a vector $v \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ right? If $v \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ then $Mv \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ is clear, the reverse is also clear as if $Mv \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ then $M^{-1}Mv \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.  If I extend this to the question I have $x$ has integer entries iff $y$ has integer entries, does this mean that no potential integer entries can be "lost" in the step of $c_i/d_i$? Thanks, I think I will play around with some examples to convince myself of this.